Connect to pub/sub within vpc without nat
I want to use gcp pub/sub both push and pull subscription within vpc without nat , similar to aws vpc endpoint is there any way to achieve the same in gcp ? I went thorugh docs of private google access but couldn't find any example for pub/sub.

In my experiance NAT ( https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview ) lets GCP resources to create outbound /egress connections (external internet, third party providers, on premises network and resources, etc.). How can NAT be used in fetching messages from the PubSub?

pub/sub is a global service and not deployed within vpc so to fetch the subscription we need internet connection same a gcs bucket.  i don't want my packet to travel to internet while calling pull subscription , same with push subscription endpoint

Actually this is well documented for Pub/Sub that you can use private service connect. https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#config mentions *.googleapis.com is allowed and the pub/sub api endpoint is https://pubsub.googleapis.com. You don't need a NAT

@Puteri, just to be exact, and even if PSC is very trendy right now, the feature is private Google Access that you set on your subnet: https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/configure-private-google-access#config-pga But it works only when the traffic comes from the VPC (thus for the pull mode). For the push, it's not yet possible, you must use a bridge for that, like Cloud Run, with a direct VPC egress for instance to invoke the correct target in the VPC from push message coming from PubSub: https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/connecting-vpc

@Abhinav Even if you put a Cloud NAT, you paquet won't go over the internet as long as you have a network premium tiers.

@guillaumeblaquiere you’re correct. Totally missed the push feature. In that case as you mention it's imposible in a native way c:

no , that i know , done for cloud storage, like if i need to call any subscription and my psc dns name is xyz how can i directly call that subscription from my compute engine  would it be pubsub-xyz.p.googleapis.com, aplogies if its a stupid question

like for bucket we have curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Bearer $(gcloud auth print-access-token)"   "https://storage-endpoint-name.p.googleapis.com./storage/v1/b/bucket-name/  , couldn't find similar command to the message from subscription
